Prove, that the sequence $\{vdi(P_n)\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is increasing, where $P_n$ is a path of order $n$ and $vdi()$ is the vertex distinguishing index
Definitions
Let $G$ be a graph. The vertex distinguishing index $vdi(G)$ is the minimum number of colors required for a proper edge coloring of $G$ such that any pair of vertices have distinct sets of colors.

I can't find anything on the internet about it. But it seems kind of intuitive. Can't I just argue that the only way to obtain a coloring such that any pair of vertices have distinct sets of colors is to color each edge differently, and thus $vdi(P_n)$ must be increasing the more edges (= the bigger the $n$) I add?

Well, the first claim in your argument is false; for example, if you color a path of length $4$ with the edge colors "red, blue, blue, green", then all $5$ vertices are still distinguishable, even though you used a color twice.

@MishaLavrov The edge coloring has to be proper, so we need a bit bigger example, for instance, a path of length $5$ with the edge colors "red, green, blue, yellow, green".

We suppose that $n\ge 3$, because the number $vdi(P_n)$ exists only for such $n$. Next, it is easy to check that $vdi(P_5)=vdi(P_6)=4$, so I guess in the question "increasing" means "nondecreasing".
Then it suffices for any natural $n\ge 4$ and any proper edge coloring of $P_n$ such that any pair of vertices have distinct sets of colors to construct an edge coloring of $P_{n-1}$ such that any pair of vertices have distinct sets of colors. Since the edge coloring is proper, each nonend vertex of $P_n$ has two colors. For any natural $i\le n-1$ let $c_i$ be the color of the $i$th edge. Since the second and the previous to the last vertices of $P_n$ have distinct sets of colors, $\{c_1,c_2\}\ne \{c_{n-2},c_{n-1}\}$. Thus either $c_2\ne c_{n-1}$ or $c_1\ne c_{n-2}$. In the former case the removal of the first vertex of $P_n$ provides the required edge coloring of $P_{n-1}$, in the latter case the removal of the last vertex of $P_n$ provides the required edge coloring of $P_{n-1}$.
